# Bitcoin Wallet Transaction Callback

Tags: php, http, transactions, bitcoin

Is it possible for the Bitcoin client (running in server mode) to send a HTTP request upon receiving a transaction and it being confirmed? I.e. to send to a PHP script for callback/confirmation.

Comment: This would probably get a better response in the Bitcoin SE site: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using the walletnotify parameter in your bitcoin.conf file.

```
walletnotify=/home/bitcoin/transaction.sh %s
```

This will call the transaction.sh script with the txid as a paramter. From there you can basically do anything.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -d "txid=$1" http://127.0.0.1/callback
```

**Note: the address you want to monitor has to be part of your wallet**

Answer (score 0):

you could parse the https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/$bitcoin_address api for new transactions

Comment: why rely on a third party when you're running your own node?